# Looseness for Bezier controls. Or how to bend in circularly symmetric tikz-drawings (without bend left, etc.)

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments, bezier

If I want to draw a something with circular symmetry, e.g joining pair of  points by arcs as shown in the picture with only two, I face the problem of not being able to use the edge bending. This is because it implies the choice of `bend left` (or right, or...) which breaks the symmetry.

I want to bend my edges to the center of the circle, but the arcs bend too much towards the center (arc in blue). I can correct, e.g. by adding a coordinate (arc in red). Isn't there an option to tell `controls ..` not to bend that much?

At the bottom there is another picture which shows what I don't want (and happens if I use `bend left`). I want in all arcs to be pulled to the center.  I cannot fix by reordering a big list manually in finite time.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{ifthen}


\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]


\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O)  circle (4);
%  
 \foreach \i in {1,2,...,8} {

 \node[draw,fill=white,circle] (p\i) at ($(O)+(360*\i/8:4)$)  {\i};
   }

\draw [blue] (p1) .. controls (O) ..  (p3); 
\draw [red] (p1) .. controls  ($(O)+.3*(p2)$)  ..  (p3); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By using, say

```
\path [violet, bend left=30, looseness=1.3]
(p1) edge (p2)
(p3) edge (p4)
(p5) edge (p6)
% since I cannot order points, I'll have 
% pairings like the next one:
(p8) edge (p7)
;
```

This is what I meant with breaking of symmetry: one of the edges 
bends the other side, and not towards the center. I cannot reorder
data in order to invert the bending-side.

[image]

Comment: For your question *'Isn't there an option to tell controls .. not to bend that much?'*, I guess the answer is 'No'. That is because `bend left` and `looseness` influence how TikZ *creates the control points for you*. If you choose the control points yourself, you bypass that logic. The path of the curve is then determined by a mathematical formula. In order for it to look different you have to pick different controls. However, you could make the calculation of the intermediate control point a bit easier by using the `barycentric cs` coordinate system. Then you don't need to know `(p2)`.

Comment: If you want symmetry, use arcs not parabolas.  Try `\draw [blue] (p1) arc[radius=4, start angle=-45, end angle=-135]; `

Comment: @JohnKormylo I cannot do that, unfortunately, for a large (7!! times 4) number of points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your question *'Isn't there an option to tell controls .. not to bend that much?'*, I guess the answer is *No*. That is because `bend left` and `looseness` influence how Ti*k*Z *creates the control points for you*. If you choose the control points yourself, you bypass that logic. The path of the curve is then determined by a mathematical formula, so in order for it to look different you have to pick different controls.

However, you could make the calculation of the intermediate control point a bit easier by using the coordinate system `barycentric cs` (see also pgfmanual 13.2.2 Barycentric Systems). Then you don't need to know the coordinate between start and end (`(p2)` in your example).

The green lines are all possible connections in your example graph, except loops. The red/blue lines show how the barycentric coordinate system works when you change the influence of the coordinate `(O)`.

[image: Example output]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (4);

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8} {
    \node[draw,fill=white,circle] (p\i) at (360*\i/8:4)  {\i};
}

% Demonstrate influence of O=\looseness in barycentric cs on (p1)--(p3)
\foreach[evaluate={\col={15*\looseness}}] \looseness in {0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, ..., 6} {
    \draw [color=blue!\col!red] (p1) .. controls (barycentric cs:p1=0.5,p3=0.5,O=\looseness) ..  (p3); 
}

% Draw all possible edges 
\tikzstyle{every edge}=[
    draw, green,
    to path={
        .. controls (barycentric cs:\tikztostart=0.5,\tikztotarget=0.5,O=0.3) ..
        (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
]
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 8}{
    \foreach \j in {1, ..., 8}{
        \ifnum\i=\j\else
            \draw [green] (p\i) edge (p\j); 
        \fi
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With `bend left`, you should be able to get what you want (unless I totally misundertsood your demand)... but you have to pay attention to the order of the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]


\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O)  circle (4);
%  
 \foreach \i in {1,2,...,8} {

 \node[draw,fill=white,circle] (p\i) at ($(O)+(360*\i/8:4)$)  {\i};
   }
\foreach \i/\j in {1/3,2/4,3/5,4/6,5/7,6/8,7/1,8/2}{
\draw [blue] (p\i) .. controls (O) ..  (p\j); 
\draw [red] (p\i) .. controls  ($(O)+.3*(p2)$)  ..  (p\j); 
\draw [green,bend left,looseness=1.5] (p\i) edge (p\j); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** A proposal with number sorting so that the actual plot is always done in increasing node numbers.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]


\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O)  circle (4);
%  
 \foreach \i in {1,2,...,8} {

 \node[draw,fill=white,circle] (p\i) at ($(O)+(360*\i/8:4)$)  {\i};
   }
\foreach \ii/\jj [
    evaluate={\ii as \i using ifthenelse(\jj<\ii,int(\jj),int(\ii))},
    evaluate={\jj as \j using ifthenelse(\jj<\ii,int(\ii),int(\jj))},
] in {1/2,3/4,5/6,7/8,7/6}{
\draw [blue] (p\i) .. controls (O) ..  (p\j); 
\draw [red] (p\i) .. controls  ($(O)+.3*(p2)$)  ..  (p\j); 
\draw [green,bend left,looseness=1] (p\i) edge (p\j); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I cannot order the coordinates. (p1) to (p2) doesn't bend as (p2) to (p1), but opposite. That's why I wrote in the title without using bend left.

Comment: @c.p. Could you show an example of what you want to achieve ? Also, you say that you cannot order the points, but for instance do you know the total amount of points that you will get or other imprtant parameter of your plot ?

Comment: it's more or less double factorial (of 7, I guess 105 diagrams). I cannot order them manually. I'll edit.

Comment: @c.p. Just posted an improved version, which sorts nodes by index

Comment: thanks, that helps :)

Comment: Just a nitpick: Your examples don't have circular symmetry because of the `(p2)` in `($(O)+.3*(p2)$)`.

Comment: @Fritz, yep that is just because it was the case in the original post...